# Docker ps command into XARGS command to check and auto restart unhealthy containers

Tags: docker, xargs

`docker ps -f health=unhealthy --format "docker restart {{.ID}}" | xargs --no-run-if-empty -t docker restart`

output is :

> docker restart docker restart 7c20974e2b02
>
> 7c20974e2b02
>
> Error response from daemon: No such container: docker
>
> Error response from daemon: No such container: restart

How do I not get the "Error response from daemon: No such container: "

Comment: Notice the repetition in `docker restart docker restart 7c20974e2b02`; the command you want is just `docker restart 7c20974e2b02`.

Answer (score 0):

Take `docker restart` out of the format string; it should *only* be on the argument list.

```
docker ps -f health=unhealthy --format "{{.ID}}" |
  xargs --no-run-if-empty -t docker restart
```

When you had it in both places you were passing the string `docker restart` at least twice whenever xargs invoked anything at all.

---

Alternately, consider doing this without xargs entirely. Assuming that the number of unhealthy nodes is short enough to fit on a single command line -- generally a safe assumption, since the combined environment + argument length limit is typically in the range of 128KB on modern systems:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a unhealthy_nodes < <(
  docker ps -f --health=unhealthy --format '{{.ID}}' && printf '\0'
) && (( ${#unhealthy_nodes[@]} )) &&
  docker restart "${unhealthy_nodes[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have both `docker ps` with its `--format` option and `xargs` putting `docker restart` in front of the container name. You need to do one or the other. Removing the format option will have `docker ps` only pass the container ID to `xargs` which will run it as an additional argument to `docker restart` that it already has:

```
docker ps -f health=unhealthy --format "{{.ID}}" | xargs --no-run-if-empty -t docker restart
```

Or you can remove restart from xargs and just have format add that by itself:

```
docker ps -f health=unhealthy --format "restart {{.ID}}" | xargs --no-run-if-empty -t docker
```

xargs always requires the base command so you can't pass `docker` in the format, but all other arguments can be fed into it. I'd recommend the former approach. This latter example is more to demonstrate the difference between each option. Also, if `docker ps` ever returns more than one ID, you only want `restart` to appear once as it will in the former case.

Comment: Why demonstrate an option you know is buggy, vs removing it and showing only the correct one?

Comment: (also, is there anything you're covering here that I missed in the answer posted roughly seven minutes prior?)

Comment: When I started writing my answer, there was no other answer. I did not see your answer until I hit Post with my answer. As for the "buggy" answer, I first included that line before I had fully tested it out and reasoned through it. After I realized the issue with it, I decided to keep it in just to demonstrate to the OP as an example of how the format string and xargs arguments interact with each other.